# why i cant set position of Label using setbounds method in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
import javax.swing.; 
import java.awt.event.; 
import java.awt.*; 

class login extends JFrame { 

  public static void main(String args[]) { 

      JFrame f1; 
      JLabel l1,l2,l3; 
      JButton sign,cancle; 
      f1 =new JFrame();
      l1= new JLabel("hi"); 
      f1.add(l1);
      l1.setBounds(170,40,75,25); 
      f1.setSize(500,500); 
      f1.setVisible(true);
      f1.setLayout(null); 
  } 
}
```

I cant set position of a label with using Setbounds method kindly give me a solution for this..!!

Comment: I'm sure you don't write all you code on a single line like that so don't expect us to read code like that. Edit your question and proper format the code. Also, you should even be attempting to use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: Please reformat and post your example as a code block to make it easier to read

Comment: And don't use `setLayout(null)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
f1.setVisible(true);
```

When you invoke `setVisible(true)`, the layout manager of the frame is invoked and the components are given a size and location based on the rules of the layout manager, which by default is a BorderLayout.

The setLayout(null) statement has no effect on components already visible on the frame because the bounds you manually set have been reset by the layout manager.

Anyway, don't attempt to use a null layout. There is no reason for doing this. [Use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).